# Check to see if CMD is idle when used as a process

Tags: c#, cmd, process

**Problem:** Issue with the number of files passed to CMD utility.

**Desired Solution:** Way to be able to check that CMD has finished converting file before incrementing loop.

I'm running a utility in CMD using a user interface in C#. The utility converts audio files from .vce to .wav. If more that 30 files are selected the utility gets overwhelmed and stops working. How can I check to see that it has finished with one file conversion before the loop is incremented? `.WaitForExit()` and `.WaitForProcessIdle()` both did not work.

```
//arguments are a list of files selected by the user for conversion, 
//the folder to save the converted files in, and the path that the 
//current files are under
public static void convertVCE(List<string> files, string newPath, string filePath)
{
    Process process1 = new Process();
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process1.Start();
    //move to directory where the utility is
    process1.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd \\Program Files (x86)\\NMS Utilities");
    process1.StandardInput.Flush();

    //loop to convert each selected file
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        if (files[i].EndsWith(".vce"))
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, files[i]);
            string newFileName = Path.Combine(newPath, files[i]).Replace(".vce", "");
                
            process1.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("vcecopy.exe {0} {1}.wav", fileName, newFileName));
            process1.StandardInput.Flush();
        }
    }
    process1.StandardInput.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    process1.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a *cmd.exe* process? Start a *vcecopy* process and wait for that one to go idle.

Comment: can you look for the output with process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); and use that as the completion indicator?

Comment: I'm unable to just start vcecopy. In order to start it I would also have to pass it the file names it is expecting. The only way I could do it would be to open a new window for each file I wanted to convert.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like vcecopy.exe is not a console application - otherwise cmd.exe would wait for it to finish.  Have you considered using start /wait to wait for an instance of vcecopy.exe to exit before starting the next one.

Comment: Yes, you create one *vcecopy.exe* process at a time and wait for it to finish before launching the next. That's what you want isn't it? I don't understand your issue with the file names,  simply define the corresponding arguments on each launch via de `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` property.

Comment: I could be starting as many as 200 processes. I was trying to figure out a way that wouldn't requite all the time for window open/ close. I just need to make sure that the file has been successfully copied prior to the next `.WriteLine`. If opening a new vcecopy each time is the only way then I will explore that option.

Comment: What window? You don't need to open any windows if vcecopy doesn't need them. The only window you are creating is cmd.exe and you don't need it, you can launch all vcecopy executions without cmd.exe and without a single window of the app if it can run windowless.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe, just maybe, you've selected the wrong tool for the job? If you need to be making so many conversions, firing off separate processes to do so probably isn't correct. Is there not some library you could obtain that would allow you to perform the same activity in-process and more naturally control the number of parallel activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an unneeded *cmd.exe* process. You need to create *vcecopy.exe* processes and wait for them to finish as you launch them. Something along the following lines (I can't test this now, I'm coding on memory, but you should get the idea):

```
var vceCopyStartInfo = new StartInfo();
vceCopyStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
vceCopyStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
vceCopyStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\Program Files (x86)\\NMS Utilities";
vceCopyStartInfo.FileName = "vcecopy.exe";

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    if (files[i].EndsWith(".vce"))
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, files[i]);
        string newFileName = Path.Combine(newPath, files[i]).Replace(".vce", "");
        //some applications need arguments in quotes, try it if this doesn't work.
        vceCopyStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}.wav", fileName, newFileName));

        using (var vceCopyProcess = Process.Start(vceCopyStartInfo))
        {
            vceCopyProcess.WaitForExit();
            //if vcecopy doesn't exit by itself when it finishes, try WaitForProcessIdle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! I had done some of what you suggested but the "WaitForExit" was the kicker. Thanks for your help. This worked perfectly on a large number of files.